# need jquery tooltip with close feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need a jquery tooltip with the following features. The tooltip should have close button. The same tooltip can be used in more than one places in one single webpage. I keep on searching in google but still i couldn't find the expected tooltip. How can i find that?

Comment: I'd say search some more. I'm sure I've seen plenty of tooltip libraries like that

Comment: I need to complete this task today. I don't have enough time to keep on searching. So only i seek your help.Please mention any url with the features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this one you like

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/